# Laravel 4 Eloquent ORM - Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException Cannot redeclare class WorkProcess

Tags: class, exception, laravel, eloquent, redeclare

Here's the scenario!!!

Schema for (**work_processes**)

```
Schema::create('work_processes', function($table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->enum('wp_type',array('M','F','D')); //M => Maintenance, F => Field, D => Drilling 
    $table->string('wp_name',50);
    $table->integer('wp_owner_id');
    $table->integer('wp_editor_id');
    $table->text('wp_link');
    $table->enum('wp_frequency',array('B','M','Q')); //B => Bi-Monthly, M => Monthly, Q => Quarterly 
    $table->date('wp_startdate');
    $table->date('wp_enddate');
    $table->enum('wp_active',array('Y','N'));
    $table->timestamp('deleted_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});}
```

Schema for (**wp_audit_questions**)

```
Schema::create('wp_audit_questions', function($table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('wp_id');
    $table->text('wp_audit_question');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Model 1 as (**WorkProcess**)

```
class WorkProcess extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'work_processes';
    protected $guarded = array('id');
    protected $softDelete = true;

    public function wpauditquestions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('WpAuditQuestion');
    }
}
```

Model 2 as (**WpAuditQuestion**)

```
class WpAuditQuestion extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'wp_audit_questions';
    public function workprocess()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('WorkProcess', 'wp_id');
    }
}
```

'Controller as (**WorkProcessController**)

```
class WorkProcessController extends BaseController
{
    public function ShowWpAuditQuestionEditForm($wpid)
    {
        $wp = WorkProcess::with(array('wpauditquestions' => function($query){
            $query->where('wp_id', $wpid);
        }))->get();
        return View::make('wpauditquestion')->with(array('edit_mode' => 1, 'wpauditquestion' => $wpauditquestion));
    }
}
```

'Controller as (**WpAuditQuestionController**)

```
class WpAuditQuestionController extends BaseController
{
    public function ShowWPAuditQuestionForm()
    {
        $wpauditquestion = new WpAuditQuestion();
                return View::make('wpauditquestion', compact('wpauditquestion'));
     }
}
```

**Routes.php**

```
//model binding
Route::model('workprocess', 'WorkProcess');
Route::model('wpauditquestion', 'WpAuditQuestion');

Route::get('wpauditquestion/edit/{wpid}', array('uses' => 'WorkProcessController@ShowWpAuditQuestionEditForm', 'as' => 'wpauditquestion.edit'));
```

**Problem:**

This script generates this error message. e.g. MY_SERVER/wpauditquestion/edit/1

> **Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>
>   Cannot redeclare class WorkProcess**

however, when I don't use the get() or any other method like paginate(5) etc, it does dump some data.

I have also tried this but same result.

```
$wp = WorkProcess::has('wpauditquestions')->get();
```

can someone please guide me what wrong I'm doing. I'm using laravel 4.0.7 with WAMP.

Also please guide me how to save this model after editing it e.g. if I have a form like this.

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'WorkProcessController@PostWorkProcessEditForm', 'method' => 'put')) }}
{{-- Work Process Name --}}
{{ Form::hidden('wp_id') }}
<ol>
@for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    <p>
        <li> 
            {{ Form::label('wp_audit_question', 'Audit Question') }}
            {{ Form::text('wp_audit_question', Input::old('wp_audit_question')) }}
    </p>
@endfor
</ul>
<p>{{ Form::submit('Submit Form', array('id' => 'Submit_Form')) }}</p>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved! The problem was the model name **'WorkProcess'** was clashing with something as I've my view name as **'workprocess.blade.php'** as well. So I changed model name to **'WPModel'** and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you name your migration work_process which was turned into WorkProcess? It can be that your migration has same class name as your model.

Comment: smartman, No, the migration is as it is i.e. ***work_processes***. Thats why I've added this line to the model ***WorkProcess***  
***protected $table = 'work_processes';***

Answer (score 0):

in case you did something like changing a class name.

Let's say you changed the class name of your model from '**`users`**' to '**`user`**',

You could try running the command '**`composer dump-autoload`**'.

It worked for me though my case was not exactly the same as yours.